# OpenCV: speed up remaping

Tags: opencv, remap

I am using Allwinner processor without any GPU acceleration. The problem is that remap() funtion takes about 20ms to remap 640x480 3 bytes image. It is too much for me. I compiled with multiprocessing  flag (MP) and tried to write me own piece of code. 
Any ideas how to speed up this function or what can I make on (ORANGE-PI H3) to get some GPU acceleration of this function?

Comment: What kind of GPU does your board have? Does it support OpenCL?

Comment: Mali 400, it does not support any acceleration suitabled for OpenCV

Comment: Then you cannot give OpenCV GPU support if your on board chip does not support OpenCL/CUDA.

Comment: Please share your own code - there are some smart folks on StackOverflow...

Comment: Also, try tagging your question with `SIMD` and `NEON`.